# How to evaluate a NA value in an if statement in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I have a dataset and I need to use an IF statement to evaluate every value in the 5th column. If it is positive, it should say 'Up' otherwise it should say 'Not up'. The problem is that at the end of each day I would have 5 NA values and my statement does not know how to evaluate those. My dataset would look something like:

```
 379    949 2115    2015-02-20  0   Not Up
 380    950 2115    2015-02-20  -5  Not Up
 381    951 2115    2015-02-20  -5  Not Up
 382    952 2115    2015-02-20  -5  Not Up
 383    953 2115    2015-02-20  -5  Not Up
 384    954 2115    2015-02-20  -5  Not Up
 385    955 2110    2015-02-20  0   Not Up
 386    956 2110    2015-02-20  NA  Up
 387    957 2110    2015-02-20  NA  Up
 388    958 2110    2015-02-20  NA  Up
 389    959 2110    2015-02-20  NA  Up
 390    960 2110    2015-02-20  NA  Up
 391    571 2075    2015-02-23  15  Up
 392    572 2075    2015-02-23  15  Up
 393    573 2085    2015-02-23  0   Up
 394    574 2085    2015-02-23  -5  Up
 395    575 2085    2015-02-23  -5  Up
 396    576 2090    2015-02-23  -15 Up
 397    577 2090    2015-02-23  -20 Up
```

As you can see, after the NA values the If statement fails to evaluate and output what I need correctly.

Any help on how to deal with the 'NA' values would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want "Not up" for the NAs values:

```
df$x6 <- ifelse(df$x5 > 0 & !is.na(df$x5), "Up", "Not Up")
```

Output:

```
    x1  x2   x3         x4  x5     x6
1  379 949 2115 2015-02-20   0 Not Up
2  380 950 2115 2015-02-20  -5 Not Up
3  381 951 2115 2015-02-20  -5 Not Up
4  382 952 2115 2015-02-20  -5 Not Up
5  383 953 2115 2015-02-20  -5 Not Up
6  384 954 2115 2015-02-20  -5 Not Up
7  385 955 2110 2015-02-20   0 Not Up
8  386 956 2110 2015-02-20  NA Not Up
9  387 957 2110 2015-02-20  NA Not Up
10 388 958 2110 2015-02-20  NA Not Up
11 389 959 2110 2015-02-20  NA Not Up
12 390 960 2110 2015-02-20  NA Not Up
13 391 571 2075 2015-02-23  15     Up
14 392 572 2075 2015-02-23  15     Up
15 393 573 2085 2015-02-23   0 Not Up
16 394 574 2085 2015-02-23  -5 Not Up
17 395 575 2085 2015-02-23  -5 Not Up
18 396 576 2090 2015-02-23 -15 Not Up
19 397 577 2090 2015-02-23 -20 Not Up
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(x1 = 379:397, x2 = c(949L, 950L, 951L, 952L, 953L, 
954L, 955L, 956L, 957L, 958L, 959L, 960L, 571L, 572L, 573L, 574L, 
575L, 576L, 577L), x3 = c(2115L, 2115L, 2115L, 2115L, 2115L, 
2115L, 2110L, 2110L, 2110L, 2110L, 2110L, 2110L, 2075L, 2075L, 
2085L, 2085L, 2085L, 2090L, 2090L), x4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("2015-02-20", "2015-02-23"), class = "factor"), 
    x5 = c(0L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    15L, 15L, 0L, -5L, -5L, -15L, -20L)), .Names = c("x1", "x2", 
"x3", "x4", "x5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L
))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ifelse` to handle this extra case:

```
function(x) { ifelse(is.na(x), "Unknown", ifelse(x > 0, "Up", "Not Up")) }
```

---

If you want it to say "Not Up" for NA values, use:

```
function(x) { ifelse(is.na(x) | x <= 0, "Not Up", "Up") }
```

Comment: Very often, when I'm writing `ifelse` statements like this, I write explicitly what I want to happen to `NA`'s just so that I don't get surprised later on.  I'd recommend developing that habit.

Comment: You need to replace `||` with `|` (the vectorised version) for this to work.